# Cannot get Latitude and Longitude to be stored in a variable

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to get the lat, lon variable to be used again, but when I set it at the onConnected(), it does not set in the MainActivity.
here's my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
protected Context context;
double lat, lon;
TextView txtLat;
double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();


}
```

and here's the other part that include the get lat long.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Connected to Google Play Services!");

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        lat = lastLocation.getLatitude();
        lon = lastLocation.getLongitude();
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtLat.setText(lat + " " + lon);
    }

}
```

Comment: what `double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;` this for is this you want to reused again?

Comment: @ntaloventi no. The lat, lon

Answer (score 1):

Having the location permission allowed and having the location enabled is not the same thing (i.e : user can allow the location permission but the location is not enable so LastLocation maybe empty)
You can for example :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if (gps_enabled || network_enabled) {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1001);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(GoogleClient, this);   
                   lat = location.getLatitude();
                   lon = location.getLongitude();   
                }
            });
        }
```